# What is this green stuff on the fountain?

Tags: cleaning, chemicals, pressure-washer, fountain

If it matters, I'm west-coast USA.

I have this water fountain:

[image: Photo of water fountain with green stuff on it]

I'd like to clean it to remove this green stuff on it, but I don't know what it is. I'd also like to remove the white around where the water is [when it's turned on].

How should I remove it?

A hose did a decent job, but took a long time and it's still fairly green. Maybe a pressure washer? Chemicals?

Answer (score 2):

The white is probably lime or calcium deposits. The green is algae.

A cleaner such as CLR or will work on the white stuff, or you can try to brush it off with a wire brush. It is a product of the minerals in the water so eventually it will come back.

There is an [outdoor bleach](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Clorox-121-oz-Pro-Results-Concentrated-Liquid-Outdoor-Bleach-Cleaner-4460032437/311787164) that is safe for plants. The rocks getting wet and drying slow will regrow the algae as well.

You could look into chemicals to put into the water  if it is a recyclable type of system. However there is a trade off there as well. Chlorine can cause early    breakdown of soft components in the pumping system.

Bottom line is any fountain/ pond is requiring cleaning and maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you clarify if something like a pressure washer would remove the algae or if I'd want a chemical of some type? I might try that for the white stuff, but I'm wondering about removing the algae ...

Comment: A pressure washer may remove the algae.....for a bit. It will also drive tiny spores deeper into the rock and the algae will come back sooner.  Better to use something to kill the organism.  A spray bottle and a brush is much easier than lugging out a PW to clean those stones . Spray, brush, spray again, let it sit for 5 min. rinse with a hose.

Comment: Is there a specific chemical you'd recommend? I haven't really had to deal with this before ...

Comment: Bleach will kill most living things.

Comment: I had a link in my answer as to what to use for the algae.

Comment: If it's a recirculating fountain you can add fish pond algaecide. It will treat your pump better.

Comment: CLR and bleach are highly reactive. They might react with the stone and cause discoloration of their own. It would be wise to spot test an unexposed area first to verify that they don't cause such discoloration. From CLR's FAQs: "DO not use CLR on natural stone or marble, terrazzo, colored grout, painted or metallic glazed surfaces, plastic laminates, Formica, aluminum, steam irons, leaded crystal, refinished tubs or any damaged or cracked surface. CLR may etch older sinks, tubs and tiles. CLR is corrosive. ...."

Comment: @popham, not disputing what you have about CLR.  However the warning is regarding processed materials and aimed at preventing an additional discoloration on an otherwise uniform surface.  In the case of the OP's fountain, they are trying to deal with an already  stained surface.  The goal is to remove the stains and marks and get back to something more natural, which the CLR and bleach will accomplish.

Comment: I'm not advocating to follow the FAQ answer. I'm advocating caution. Didn't work in 5 minutes? I wouldn't let it "soak" overnight.

Comment: @ popham, Then it would be wise to say that, not post a lot of info that was not germane to the situation.

Comment: I did say that: "It would be wise to spot test an unexposed area first to verify that they don't cause such discoloration." The FAQ excerpt is evidence supporting the advice, and it is very germane to the situation. This is "natural stone," after all.